# Getting correct row with SELECT, getting zero rows in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, rest, select, pdo

I have a serious problem

I'm mounting a REST API with PHP. So, I have a controller called "Checkestablishment" (this will check the username and password from a database).

I have the next Query

```
SELECT table_users.ID, table_users.FirstName, table_users.LastName, table_users.ZIP,     table_users.State, table_users.Country, table_users.Email, table_users.Birthday
FROM table_users, table_user_credentials
WHERE table_user_credentials.User = table_users.ID
AND table_user_credentials.Username = 'someuser'
AND table_user_credentials.Pass = 'somepass'
```

And it works fine, MySQL gets me the desired row.

But when i'm trying to execute it in PDO, I'm getting null.

This is my code

```
    public function add()
    {
        global $counect;
        $i = 0;
        $Query_CheckCredential = "SELECT table_users.ID, table_users.FirstName, table_users.LastName, table_users.ZIP,     table_users.State, table_users.Country, table_users.Email, table_users.Birthday
FROM table_users, table_user_credentials
WHERE table_user_credentials.User = table_users.ID
AND table_user_credentials.Username = ':Est_User'
AND table_user_credentials.Pass = ':Est_Pass'";
        $PS_CheckCredential = $counect->prepare($Query_CheckCredential);
        $Sucess = $PS_CheckCredential -> execute(array(
                                    ':Est_User'=>$this->str_User,
                                    ':Est_Pass'=>$this->str_Pass
                                    ));
        if($Sucess)
        {
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(1, $User_ID);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(2, $User_FirstName);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(3, $User_LastName);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(4, $User_ZIP);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(5, $User_State);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(6, $User_Country);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(7, $User_Email);
            $PS_CheckCredential -> bindColumn(8, $User_Birthday);
            //$PS_CheckCredential -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $Array_Est_Keys = array('ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ZIP', 'State', 'Country', 'Email', 'Birthday');

            $Array_Est_Keys = array_fill_keys($Array_Est_Keys, '');

            do
            {
                $Array_User['ID'] = $row['ID'];
                $Array_User['FirstName'] = $User_FirstName;
                $Array_User['LastName'] = $User_LastName;
                $Array_User['ZIP']  = $User_ZIP;
                $Array_User['State'] = $User_State;
                $Array_User['Country'] = $User_Country;
                $Array_User['Email'] = $User_Email;
                $Array_User['Birthday'] = $User_Birthday;
            }
            while($row = $PS_CheckCredential->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            if(empty($Array_User))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return $Array_User;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No luck";
            //return false;
        }
```

I tried to fetch the query by different ways, but no one solved my problem.

P.D. Sucess marks me as true, because the execution of the query was successfully, but i'm getting null (i made a print_r() for the array that i'm creating and i'm getting all the array with values in null).

Thanks for your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `':Est_User'`
in   `AND table_user_credentials.Username = ':Est_User'`

and around `':Est_Pass'` in `AND table_user_credentials.Pass = ':Est_Pass'`

Those binds in the SELECT query should not contain quotes.

Having checked for errors would have signaled it.

Such as:

```
$counect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after the DB connection is opened.

Comment: Oh my god... That was, the quotes added at my query... I feel embarrassed because the origin of my problem was very single.

Comment: @CarlosGarnicaJr. Am glad I was able to help out, *cheers Carlos*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @fred pointed out about the quotes, for `BindColumn` you need to use `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` but why do you need to use `BindColumn()` at all?

I understand `bindColumn` is a way to fetch  but I would not recommend using it because it is very confusing to split resultsets it's just odd.

The only helpful situation I can think of is if you want to rename shitty column name then maybe.

I suggest you to do it like everyone does and use `bindValue`  or `execute` directly

---

```
public function add()
{
    global $counect;
    $sql = "SELECT table_users.ID
                 , table_users.FirstName
                 , table_users.LastName
                 , table_users.ZIP
                 , table_users.State
                 , table_users.Country
                 , table_users.Email
                 , table_users.Birthday
            FROM table_users, table_user_credentials
            WHERE table_user_credentials.User = table_users.ID
                AND table_user_credentials.Username = :Est_User
                AND table_user_credentials.Pass = :Est_Pass";
    $stmt = $counect->prepare($sql);
    $success = $stmt-> execute(array(':Est_User'=>$this->str_User,
                                     ':Est_Pass'=>$this->str_Pass
                               ));
    if($success){
        //query success!
        if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //user found return data
            return $row;
        }else{
            //user not found
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        //query failed!
        var_dump($stmt->error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

- You can still improve this by getting the reason why it return false
- You can make the connection a property or an argument of the function
- You should hash password

and much more , good luck!